# how to search for a file and delete it using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

If I have a file named " mic.txt" on a Hard drive,
What are the codes that find this file and delete it ??

If batch files can't do this, What are there any other ways  ?

Comment: You're working on Windows platform, right ?

Comment: yes I'm working on windows platform ( I have windows 8 64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete_my_file.bat

```
@echo off
set file_to_delete=mic.txt
set dir_to_look_in=C:\

:: Starting loop
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /o /b "%dir_to_look_in%" ^| findstr "%file_to_delete%"') do (
    echo INFO: Deleting: %%f
    del /q "%%f"
)
```

Comment: Alex, Thank you very much for your answers but I have 2 questions :
1 - do these codes search in c:\ only or the whole hard drive ?

Comment: 2- I've windows 8 64-bit and when I run the batch file it says :
'C:\Windows\system32>' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
INFO: deleting : %f
could Not find C:\windows\system32\%f

Comment: it's the root (start) directory to start searching at, it should find the file(s)/folder(s) in something like C:\users\myuser\appdata\local\temp\mic.txt

If it's located on the `D:\`, adjust the script for that